# добавление классов к предыдущим элементам

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь решить задачу со звездным рейтингом.
При наведении на любую из звезд, данной звезде должен ставиться класс  golden, также такой класс должен ставиться всем звездам до нее слева.

```js
"use strict";

const starsContainer = document.querySelector('.stars_container');
const stars = document.querySelectorAll('.fas');

starsContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  let item = e.target;
  if (item.classList.contains('fas')) {
    Array.from(stars).forEach((el, index, arr) => {
      item.classList.add('golden');
      item = item.previousElementSibling;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
i {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.golden {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="stars_container">
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

Когда мы уводим курсор мыши от звезды, все поставленные классы golden должны быть удалены.

кое что написал, однако, получаю ошибку:

```
Error {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 35,
  "colno": 12
}
```

В консоле:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не обязательно использовать JS.
В CSS есть селектор `~`, позволяющий выбрать соседние элементы, которые находятся на этом же уровне вложенности, после указанного элемента.
Чтобы это заработало, нужно изменить порядок следования звездочек. В этом нам поможет `flex`:

```css
i {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.stars_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fas:hover,
.fas:hover~.fas {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="stars_container">
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Прошу любить и жаловать мой вариант)

```js
const stars = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-star');

for (let i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
  stars[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    changeStarrt(i);
  })
}

function changeStarrt(num) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
    stars[i].classList.add('golden');
  }

  for (let i = stars.length - 1; i > num; i--) {
    stars[i].classList.remove('golden');
  }
}
```

```css
i {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.golden {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="stars_container">
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: благодарю, Есть мысль в какую сторону двигаться, однако, всегда одна звезда остается. Попробую условие добавить.